# Dynamically build java/scala method body at runtime and execute it

Tags: java, scala, reflection

Suppose I have the following Interface in java:

```
public interface DynamicMethod {
    String doit();
}
```

I would like to build an Object during runtime which conforms to the above interface such that I inject doit method body in it and then execute it? Is this possible with Java Reflection API, or any other way? Or probably in some way in Scala?

Note that `doit` body for my objects would be dynamic and are not known a priori. You can assume that in run-time an array `CodeArray[1..10]` of Strings is provided and each entry of this array holds the code for each doit method. I would appreciate if you could answer with a sample code.

---

**The context:**
I try to explain the context of the problem; nonetheless, the above question still remains independent from the context.

I have some commands say C1,C2, ...; each command has certain parameters. Based on a command and its parameters the system needs to perform a certain task (which is expressible using a java code.) I need that these commands are stored for future execution based on user demand (so the `CodeArray[1..10]` in the above holds this list of java codes). For example, a user chooses a command from the list (i.e., from the array) and demands its execution.

My thought is that I build an engine that based on the user selection, loads the corresponding command code from the array and executes it.

Comment: Yes, with reflection.  Look at [Proxy class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

With your context that you added, it sounds to me like you have an [Interpreter.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).

For example, SQL takes input like "SELECT * FROM users", parses and builds a tree of tokens that it then interprets.

Another example: Java's regex is an interpreter.  A string like "[abc]+" is compiled into tokens, and then interpreted when executed.  You can see the tokens (called `Node`s) it uses in the [source code.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.Node)

I'll try to post a simple example later, but the Interpreter Pattern doesn't use dynamically generated code.  All of the tokens are concrete classes.  You do have to define all possible (valid) user input so that you can make a token to execute it however.  SQL and regex has a defined syntax, you will need one also.

Answer (score 1):

I think Byte Buddy would be helpful in your case. It's an open source project maintained by a very well respected Java developer.

Take a look at the Learn section, they have a very detailed example there:
http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not very clear what's your aim. There are many approaches to do this depending on your requirements.

In some cases it would be enough to create a [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and an [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html). Sometimes it's reasonable to generate Java source, then invoke [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) in runtime and load the generated class using [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) (probably that's your case if you're speaking about strings of code). Sometimes it's better to directly create a bytecode using libraries like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) or [BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).

Comment: Intermediate between invoking the Java compiler and directly generating byte codes, there's Aspect Oriented Programming.  [Link 1](http://docs.jboss.org/aop/1.1/aspect-framework/userguide/en/html/what.html)  [Link 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Comment: For me personally, it's the "dynamic and not known *a priori.*"  How and when do you know what you are going to do?  Why can't you just extend the interface?  Also, what environment will you be using?

Comment: @Tagir Valeev, I am looking for an alternative *concrete* solution for the problem I described above. Would you please add how this doable, for example with reflection, compilation and ... .

Comment: @markspace, the answer is during the application run time; the method bodies are build based on user inputs during application run-time.

Comment: Can you give an example yourself of some code?  I'm having a hard time imagining how you go from "user input" to some sort of dynamically generated method.

Comment: @markspace, I am in the design phase, and the code is very bulky to communicate anything at the moment. But I added some context to the question. it may clarify the design problem.